# Beginner looking for advice regarding the calling of a member function using objects and pointers to objects

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm fairly new with C++ and am having issues figuring how to properly call the member function using each of the objects of a class we are working on.  The question is given to us as a separate function with the actual class (`SuperClass`) being hidden.  The function is as follows:

```
void UseingObjects( SuperClass& super_class_1, SuperClass* super_class_2, SuperClass** super_class_3) {

}
```

I need to call the hidden member function `SuperMethod` using each of the objects (`super_class_1`, `super_class_2`, and `super_class_3`) as well as set the member variable "Super_Member" to the value of 35 in each instance.

I realize that pointers are being used in the parameters and that is what is throwing me off because we have only just started on classes and have yet to dive deep into pointers.  Any help on where to get started is greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In C++ class members/methods could be either `private`, `protected` or `public`. There is no such thing as hidden members. If your `Super_Method` is a public method, then you could access it that way:

```
void UseingObjects( SuperClass& super_class_1, SuperClass* super_class_2, SuperClass** super_class_3) 
{
  super_class_1.Super_Method();
  super_class_2->Super_Method();
  (*super_class_3)->Super_Method();
}
```

Comment: do you know when do we use `**` it should be an array of pointers right?

Comment: @Ghooo It could be an array of pointers, or could be simple pointer of pointer, there is no way to tell without knowing implementation details.